# Questions regarding personalized code

Tags: discussion

Is it fine to ask for solutions or suggestions on personalized code? Code that may not necessarily be the exact one someone else uses but may be encountering the same or a similar issue?

Comment: Most of the questions on SO are like that

Comment: It depends on the question. If the question is likely to have value for someone else doing a similar thing, that's ok. If it's useful only to you, it may not be on topic.

Comment: As stated it sounds very broad, opinion based. Both are reasons to close vote a question.

Comment: SO is a repository of knowledge of question and answer, not suggestion, so you need to have a clear question to be solved. Usually on SO we require that you tryed yourself something so we can tell you why it didn't work, don't ask for the whole code.